# Error installing xserver-xorg-video-* package from squeeze-backports in Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, xorg, drivers, backports

I wanted to upgrade my Intel Core i[357] Integrated Graphics (Arrandale) driver so that DRI would work.
But some packages were broken in the middle of the installation.

```
username@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install -t squeeze-backports xserver-xorg-core
...
dpkg: regarding .../xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.10.3-1~bpo60+1_amd64.deb containing xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core breaks xserver-xorg-input-7
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics provides xserver-xorg-input-7 and is present and installed.
...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.10.3-1~bpo60+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 installing xserver-xorg-core would break existing software
configured to not write apport reports
...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.10.3-1~bpo60+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
username@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install -t squeeze-backports xserver-xorg-core
...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.10.2-4) but 7.7.1-4 is to be installed
                     Breaks: xserver-xorg-input-7
                     Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-6
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev : Depends: xorg-input-abi-7.0
...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).               
username@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install -t squeeze-backports xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-dri
...
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-intel1 (>= 2.4.23-3~) but 2.4.21-1~squeeze3 is to be installed
 xserver-xorg-core : Breaks: xserver-xorg-input-7
                     Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-6
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev : Depends: xorg-input-abi-7.0
...
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

1. How do I clean this up?
2. How do I get the packages to install?

Comment: For #2 see http://x.debian.net/reference/squeeze-backports.html

Comment: And for #1, have you attempted `apt-get -f install` yet, as the program itself advises?

Comment: Yes- it removes packages I need:

Comment: `~$ sudo apt-get -f install
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-video-all
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
..Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
..Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau1a (2.4.26-1~bpo60+1) ...`

Comment: So then I do `username@hostname:~$ sudo apt-get install  xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-video-all   xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` to put those back, and check in synaptics for any that got upgraded and left that way (there was one) and downgrade it there.  Does that downgrade leave it pinned?

Comment: You want to check what x packages you already have installed, and install those all at once. And really, you would be better off trying this in a separate test system.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic piece of advice in this kind of situation; I don't know if it'll work in this particular case.

Run `aptitude` and see what it proposes to resolve the conflicts (press `,` and `.` to navigate between the proposed solutions, press `g` if you find a satisfying one.

Comment: This can also be done in CLI mode with `aptitude install -f` in his case. Unfortunately, the aptitude dependency resolver doesn't seem to work as well as it used to.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are the problem:

```
xserver-xorg-core : Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.10.2-4) \
    but 7.7.1-4 is to be installed
libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.10.2-4) but 7.7.1-4 is to be installed
```

As far as I can tell, basically your `backports` repos for the `x..-video*` drivers want a newer version of `xserver-xorg-core` and its dependencies than whatever repo you've pulled it from. Does the `backports` repo offer that package as well? If so, you might want to update the whole `xserver` from the same repository.

Either that or I've got it backwards and the `backports` stuff is too old for your current kit and vice-versa - but you'll probably want to singly source the whole metapackage in any case.

Sorry if that's too vague - I don't Debian much.

I suppose a different solution might be had by just manually overriding dependencies and choosing the newer version of all packages available - but that would require you to cross your fingers at the very least, which isn't always a sure thing either, I've found.

Looking a little closer and just a little ways up there's:

```
dpkg: error processing \
    /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.10.3-1~bpo60+1_amd64.deb \
(--unpack): installing xserver-xorg-core would break existing software
```

You should at least clear the package cache. Your package manager appears to be trying to install an older version of `xserver-xorg-core` to handle the driver updates from your local package cache directory on disk - it should probably be downloading a new version of that. It might not be doing so on its own due to the `input` package listed before that or maybe just because you need to update your repo lists first, or maybe because you need to add another repo.